# Where does Android Studio install the Android SDK and tools?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I need direct access to the location of the android developer tools and can't find where Android Studio saved them. I am on a Mac. Thanks!

Comment: They're not in studio's application folder?

Comment: They are not. I am running version 1.2

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you were asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here: *~/Library/Android/sdk*

If you didn't change it

If you change it, you can find where using the SDK Manager:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click on the "SDK Manager" icon. [image: icon]

When the window open, you'll see on the top:

SDK path: ...

[image: path]

Comment: OP is on a Mac, not Windows. It might not change anything, but I figured it was worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

/Users//Library/Android/sdk/

[Source](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio)

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to open up Finder and search for files that are specific to the Android SDK, such as:

- fastboot
- adb
- hprof-conv
- draw9patch
- ddms

Not an exhaustive list, but you get the point.
Then right click (in the search) and choose 'Reveal in Finder'.

This will be a good way if, for some reason, you cannot use the answer by Sandro

Answer (score 1):

User/NameOFYourComputer/App/sdk
if you want to see the full path go to android studio the lunch menu 
1 - click on Configure
2 - projetct default
3 - project structure